inconsistent django session key
I am implementing a cart function which gets Session key since it doesn’t have user login. But every time I add something to the cart, it gets different Session key.
When I check the Django admin panel, it adds data to the cart but I get an empty array whenever I call my Get Cart API.
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_to_cart(request):
    try:
        session_key = request.session.session_key
        if not session_key:
            request.session.create()
            session_key = request.session.session_key

        product_id = request.data.get('product')
        quantity = request.data.get('quantity')
        size_id = request.data.get('size')

        if not all([product_id, quantity, size_id]):
            return Response({'error': 'Missing required fields'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        cart_item = Cart.objects.create(
            product_id=product_id,
            quantity=quantity,
            size_id=size_id,
            session_key=session_key
        )
        serializer = CartSerializer(cart_item)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    except Exception as e:
        return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_cart_items(request):
    session_key = request.session.session_key
    
    cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(session_key=session_key)
    serializer = CartSerializer(cart_items, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


Are you testing this in incognito mode?

no, i tested this on a normal mode

Try request.session.save() over request.session.create().

tried it and it still get a different session key from the sessionId(Application tab on dev tools)

I couldn’t reproduce this behavior.
